# Как передать данные между фрагментами через ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

Пытаюсь использовать ViewModel для передачи данных из одного фрагмента в другой, как показано здесь: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel#sharing

Но не получается. В чем может быть проблема?

`ViewModel:`

```
class NewsViewModel(
repository: NewsRepository,
query: String
) : BaseViewModel() {

val article = MutableLiveData<Article>()

fun setArticle(article: Article) {
    this.article.value = article
}

}
```

Устанавливаю значение из фрагмента и перехожу в другой:

```
  override fun onItemClick(article: Article) {
    viewModel.setArticle(article)
    view?.let { Navigation.findNavController(it).navigate(R.id.articleFragment) }
}
```

Пытаюсь получить в другом фрагменте:

```
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    viewModel.article.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        requireActivity().loadImage(it.urlToImage ?: "", collapsingImage)
        titleTextView.text = it.title
    })
}
```

Comment: Как вы получаете ViewModel во фрагментах?

Comment: с помощью Koin:  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = getViewModel { parametersOf(arguments?.get(QUERY)) }
    }

Comment: Не работал с Koin и какие там способы инжектить `ViewModel` не знаю, но наткнулся на что-то под названием `sharedViewModel` в нём. В любом случае, проблема, скорее всего, в том, что вью модель привязывается к фрагменту, а нужно привязать к активити (или к графу из navigation components)

Comment: спасибо! заменил getViewModel на getSharedViewModel все заработало)